# Apply time delta to csv column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to change all the rows in a given column to be pushed back 9 hours (-9 hours)

I can't seem to figure this out on Pandas.

```
import os, sys
import glob
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv


dirListing = '/Users/Desktop/timezone_test'
extension = 'csv'
os.chdir(dirListing)

for fname in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension)):

    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    df['Conversion Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Conversion Date'])
    for x in df['Conversion Date']:
        x.to_timedelta(hours=-9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the timedelta from the datetime column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname)
df['Conversion Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Conversion Date']) - timedelta(hours=9)
```

Comment: Thanks! your answer did the trick. Really appreciate the help!